# How to read files from USB connected phone in Python?

Tags: python, mobile, drive

I made a Python program that reads all the files in a directory who's path is inputted and then does some things to them and outputs some things into a .txt file.

I used os.walk to read the files in the directory

```
def dir_read(pathName = str(), fileList=[]):  #fileList is output
    cur_dir = [i[2] for i in os.walk(pathName)] #current directory
    for i in cur_dir:
        for j in i:
            fileList.append(j)
```

and then checking for correctly inputted paths like this

```
fileList=[]

while True:
    dir_read(pathName, fileList) #FUNCTION CALL

    if not fileList:  #if it is empty
      print("The path is written incorrectly, is empty or does not exist. Please re-enter now or "
              "close the program and enter it inside PATH.txt:")
      pathName = str(input())
    else:
        break    #if the list is not empty (the path is entered correctly) the while loop breaks
```

However if I enter something like `This PC\Nokia 6.1\Card SD` it keeps giving me the error message. Also I noticed same thing happens with things like Desktop or Documents. But if I enter something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` it works perfectly.

I tried replacing `\` with `/` as well and it doesn't work.

My phone doesn't have a specific drive like F: as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY53b.jpg

I am using Windows 10.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can use the dos `subst` command to assign a drive to your phone..

Comment: @thebjorn How? I tried following this tutorial https://www.computerhope.com/substhlp.htm and nothing happens when I type SUBST in cmd. When I type SUBST F: Nokia 6.1 I get the error message `Incorrect number of parameters - 6.1`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your directory should be like this:

on Linux:

```
media/This PC/Nokia 6.1/Card SD
```

on Windows:
You need to know the drive letter you can run this command:

```
C:\>wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename, description
```

let's say it returned X:
then your directory should be something like this:

```
X:\Nokia 6.1\Card SD
```

I'm not sure if you are supposed to remove the Nokia 6.1 or not

Answer (score 0):

try Using `subst` command and if you have spaces on your device's name put it on quotes
Ex:
`subst E: "The Name Goes Here"`